# MSACCESS 2010 VBA; Syntax Error in date in query expression

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am creating a simple database for tracking working hours. The idea is that:

1. Every day you need to input only the days that employee did not work (s*tartDate, endDate, absenceType*),
2. Then calculate working days for the whole month or selected period.

Calculation of working days should take into account weekends (saturday, sunday) and holidays from *Holiday* table.

I took a function sample from MSDN ([Counting the Number of Working Days in Access 2007](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd327646(v=office.12).aspx#Anchor_5)) and put it into a module in my MS Access 2010 db but each time I run a query I have this error.

Typically the same error appears attempting to run a query in another sample database from somewhere.

The problem is in the *strWhere* clause:

```
strWhere = "[Holiday] >=#" & startDate & "# AND [Holiday] <=#" & endDate & "#"

' Count the number of holidays.
nHolidays = DCount(Expr:="[Holiday]", Domain:=strHolidays, Criteria:=strWhere)
Workdays = nWeekdays - nHolidays
```

The error msg  from both databases is available in the link below

> Runtime Error 3075 Syntax error in date in query expression

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Where are you based? If you do not share a date format with the US then that is most likely the cause of the problem

Comment: Please show the values and types of *startDate* and *endDate*.

Comment: EU/Croatia.  My local date format is dd.mm.yyyy and it works in all of my previous Access databases.  In this one I used a code as mentioned, but in it there is no other format specified. All inputs in tables are in local format.

Comment: MS Access like all other Office applications align to your local CPU Regional Language settings which includes currency, date/time formats, and other items. Day first should not need to be re-formatted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must force a format on the string expressions for your dates. Get used to use the ISO sequence *yyyy-mm-dd* as it works everywhere:

```
strHolidays = "NameOfYourTable"
strWhere = "[Holiday] >= #" & Format(startDate, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# AND [Holiday] <= #" & Format(endDate, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#"

' Count the number of holidays.
nHolidays = DCount("*", strHolidays, strWhere)
```

Comment: This worked, but I realy need explanation why. Since all my previous databases worked fine. A link for the explanation is just fine. 
Thanks everyone.

Comment: If the local date separator is not a dot, it will most likely work - except for dates where day is <= 12 and, thus, will be taken for the _month_ if using the format dd-mm-yyyy.

Comment: So what I present as date value is one thing, and calculation is another.

Comment: Yes, the user interface is localised - so most places outside the US, date/time, currency, etc. will look different.

Answer (score 0):

In the past I have had issues where VBA doesn't always respect the regional date settings. Try forcing it into US format before concatenating it

```
strWhere = "[Holiday] >=#" & Format(startDate, "MM/dd/yyyy") & "# AND [Holiday] <=#" & Format(endDate, "MM/dd/yyyy") & "#"
```

Comment: tried but no change. In my code with no format specified it says "Syntax error in querry expression '[Holiday] >=#01.02.2017# AND [Holiday] <=#07.02.2017', and in your expample it says '[Holiday] >=#02.01.2017# AND [Holiday] <=#02.07.2017'.  So my guess is that it must be or a difference Access 2010 handles code from 2007 example, or some reference is missing, but I can't see logic in it.

Comment: Your problem is that you don't escape the **/** which then becomes the date separator which is localised. Your locale uses a dot which scrambles the SQL. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure the date is in MM/DD/YYYY order in VBA. **Always**. I generally use:

   `strWhere = "[Holiday] >= " & Format(startDate,"\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#")`
2. the second argument of DCount is *strHolidays*. That does not look like the name of a table/query. This argument should be the name of a table/query.

Comment: Answers:
1. all my previous access db's have local date/time format as dd/mm/yyyy and they work.
Only this one doesn't. 
Since in db date format is not specified different then my local dd/mm/yyyy, I don't see this can be the issue?

2.
When I mark strholidays with a mouse, a popup apperas saying "strHolidays = 'Holidays' ", which is the correct name of my table.

Comment: @Vedran in my experience, all date criteria *IN VBA* must be in US mode. Try with an ambiguous date, like #6/5/2017#. It will be understood as June 5.